# PHP regex not working and keeps giving me the error

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm stumbling on a regex issue and not sure why this validation gives me an error after entering in a correct string.

```
    // City validation
    if (empty($custom_fields["city_id"])) {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["response"] = "City field is missing. Please try again.";
        unset($_POST["s2member_pro_paypal_registration"]["nonce"]);
    } elseif (!preg_match('^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$', $custom_fields["city_id"])) {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["response"] = "Invalid City name";
        unset($_POST["s2member_pro_paypal_registration"]["nonce"]);
    }
```

I entered New York and checked the regex expression in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. It works fine but I get an error upon submitting the input string.

Can someone please assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[required regex delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)** in your `preg_match` code as this one:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$/', $custom_fields["city_id"])
```

Comment: That worked. I forgot about the regex delimiter.